# Using wildcard on other page addresses than the static ones

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, wildcard

I want to use a wildcard so any page addresses are allowed. But I want to use some static page addresses like user login, registration, and some more. I'm currently using this method but it will, as I expected, try to find `page.php` on every page address.

```
# KONTO
RewriteRule ^skapa-ett-konto$    account-create.php [L]
RewriteRule ^logga-ut$    account-logout.php [L]


# KONTO: Sidor som behöver laddas in genom jQuery/AJAX
RewriteRule ^slutfor-registreringen$    configurations/javascripts/ajax-form/account-create.php [L]
RewriteRule ^logga-in$    configurations/javascripts/ajax-form/account-login.php [L]



# --------------------------------------- #



# PROFIL
RewriteRule ^anvandare/([a-z0-9]+)$    profile.php?u=$1 [L]



# --------------------------------------- #



# ENSKILDA FILER
RewriteRule ^(.*)$    page.php?p=$1 [L]
```

How can I make so `RewriteRule` use wildcard to other page addresses than for the static ones?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood right, you want to exclude some existing pages like `login` and `registration` from the last rule. The way to exclude them is like this:

```
# ENSKILDA FILER
# Add other pages to exclude here
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(page\.php|login|registration)  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$    page.php?p=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

If all other addresses are not files, you can prefix your `page.php` rule with

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* page.php?p=$0 [L]
```